# Drop constraint before executing a delete-statement?

Tags: php, sql

as you can see in the PHP code bellow I've a delete-statement but it doesn't want to get executed. The `$arr` is an array of selected check boxes IDs witch i want to be delete when clicking on a btn.

Is it possible that i need to drop the constraint between those Ids and another table Ids first, before executing the statement?

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
include_once("./conn.php");

$arr = json_decode($_POST['arr']);

for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++){

    //drop the constrainst first here????????

    $sql = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM meting WHERE ID=?");
    $sql->bind_param('s', $arr[$i]);
    $sql->execute();
}

//header("Location: ./insert_data_measurements.php");
    
?>
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think you can post that as an answer

Comment: Removing the constraint during deletes also removes any purpose the constraint had in the first place

Comment: And if you then tried to re-apply it, it would fail as there would be rows that do not conform to the constraint anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should either manually (write some code) to delete the linked dependant rows first or set the constraint appropriately to Cascade the delete for you, automatically.

See [cascade delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) on this page of the manual

Comment: My tables are already made and there is already a constraint between my two tables (primary en foreign key). Is it possible to add the cascade option or do i need to remake the tables en set the cascade option on the foreign key

Comment: You can add the Cascade, look in the manual for the syntax